# Industry benchmark for converting visitors per month to impression

Tags: visitors, impressions

Is there any industry benchmark to convert visitors per month of a website that comes with Google Analytics report (or other such analytics software) to number of monthly impressions for basic understanding. I am in the midst of analytics data from a research report that reads 16,784 visitors per month of a category of website (https://www.a1webstats.com/resource/what-is-a-good-number-of-website-visitors-per-month). I need to get an idea of the impression (I know it will be rough estimate) associated with the same (16,784 visitors per month).

Comment: My Google Analytics data of www.digitalsplendid.net (sdslinks.blogspot.com/2019/07/blog-post.html) shows 1 user = 2.21 page views (Dec-18) in the lower end and 8.68 (Oct-18) in the higher for May 2018 - June 2019. So, an attempt to gauge impressions or page views given the number of users or visitors may fluctuate in multiple of 4, at least in this case.